# Configure apache to treat static resources with "?" character in filename

Tags: apache, url, parameters

For various reasons, I have a bunch of static resources all with the following naming format:

xxxxx?yyyyy

where the x's are regular letter chars, and the y's numbers 0-9.

Apache is truncating the filename in the GET request at the "?" - as this is traditionally used to delinate query params - and thus reporting the followying error

file xxxx not found.

How can I get Apache to not think the y's are query args, and are actually part of the static file name?

Thanks very much for help,

Don

Comment: I have employed the following work-around: create a perl script xxxx, this simply opens the file xxxx?yyyy and spits it back.

Answer (score 2):

If you have control of how the URLs are being output, you can escape the '?' chars, This would be %3F instead of the '?'.  The URL would therefore be

```
http://example.com/abcdef%3f99999
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the suggestion. Basically these files were all hosted elsewhere, and hence there's links to them. The previous server served up these static resources no problem (which was also apache, don't know what version). Basically, if someone sends request for xxx?yyy i need to cope with this.